# BufDelete running after window is closed

Tags: vimscript, neovim, buffers, vim-windows, lua

For some reason, the `BufDelete` autocommand is being executed right after a window is created, instead before, and i think it shouldn't be like that, according to the docs:

> Before deleting a buffer from the buffer list. The `BufUnload` may be called first (if the buffer was loaded). Also used just before a buffer in the buffer list is renamed.

I have a dwm-like window orchestration plugin, the editor start with window number 1, then i open window number 2, change to it, whenever i try closing window number 2 by running the comand `:TilerClose`, it prints out that the window about to be closed is number 1 (and it should be 2 instead), here's my code:

dwm-like window orchestration plugin:

```
function! tiler#close_window() abort
    let l:opened_buffers = v:lua.get_opened_buffers_count()
    let l:is_terminal = &buftype == 'terminal'
    let s:winid = win_getid()

    if opened_buffers == 1
        quit
    elseif l:is_terminal
        bdelete!
    else
        bdelete " unregister_buffer should be executed right before this
    end

    call s:set_master_layout(filter(s:get_master_layout(), 'v:val != s:winid'))
    call tiler#reorder()
    call tiler#select_master()
endfunction

command! TilerClose call tiler#close_window()
```

My Lua config:

```lua
function _G.unregister_buffer()
    print(vim.fn.winnr()) -- returns 1 instead of 2
    vim.fn.getchar() -- waits for input (prevents the print from being ignored)
end

vim.cmd("autocmd BufDelete * call v:lua.unregister_buffer()")
```

Comment: Since you're only showing us part of the code, it's really anyone's guess what's happening. But the question is confusing: you talk about bufdelete after window creation, which doesn't line up with the title. Note that `:bdelete` will close any windows showing that buffer, however.

Comment: I tested again on a vim instance running a bare-bones config with just enough code for reproducing the issue, a function, and one `BufDelete` autocommand, and yet, the same issue is happening, my windows all have different buffers, so that's not a problem, i'm just curious of why the function is not printing the window number about to be closed (i tried with both `winnr()` and `bufwinnr(expand('<abuf>'))`), somehow the autocommand is being executed **after** the window is already closed, printing another unrelated window number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all written under :h BufDelete. It is called only by the time the buffer is removed from the buffer list (think it as BufUnlisted instead).

So the current window/buffer may already change at this time (first, the buffer is unloaded/the window is closed, and only then BufDelete is triggered). And this is also mentioned in help.

Considering expand-abuf - this is a common beginner's mistake. Expand returns string while bufnr et al. think that all strngs are buffer names, not buffer numbers. Make sure to use str2nr or such.

Comment: Thanks! the tip regarding `str2nr` really helped me solve some problems i was having (the `tonumber` lua function also worked fine for converting strings to numbers)